# adding table to database causes tomcat 404 error in spring mvc app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc app that runs perfectly on tomcat server when I click `run as..run on server` from within eclipse.  However, when I add a CREATE TABLE command to the database creation code that runs on app startup, the result is a `404 error` from tomcat when any url in the app is called. The database creation code is run from xml config files in the spring app using jdbc and spring's own tools.

I have done a key word search of all files in my app by clicking `control-H` in eclipse, and the database creation script is the only file in the entire app that uses the word that is the table name.  I have not built any of the entities or controllers yet to work with the data that would be entered in the new table.  Also, I am able to add other "orphan" tables into my database from the mysql command line without causing any problems.

When I comment out the code for creating the new table, the app launches and runs perfectly.  But then when I uncomment the table creation code and try to relaunch the app, I get the same `404 error` from tomcat.

**THERE IS NO STACK TRACE.  THE ECLIPSE CONSOLE MAKES IT LOOK LIKE THE APP IS RUNNING, EVEN THOUGH IT GIVES 404 MESSAGES IN THE ABOVE DESCRIBED CONDITIONS.**

Why could the creation of a single table that is not connected to anything else cause `404 errors` in a spring mvc app using tomcat server, hibernate, and jpa, even when none of the code in any level of the app references the table yet in any way?

Comment: can you show me your web.xml, and the place where you add this script, and how you load this script

Comment: post the code you run during app start that creates this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How is the code injected into the database? [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org), [Spring's own populators](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#core.repository-populators), `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` ?
2. Have you tried to insert the code into the database manually after the application started?
3. Have you increased the log level of your app? Some kinds of insert might just cause a warning.

Please post the logs with log level set to `DEBUG` for the relevant classes and modules. That would be you database driver class, your ORM and any classes and modules involved.